# Get the amount of days there were no records Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date, count

I have a table with all the consumptions made by the hosts at an hotel, which has a date and a "cleaning-lady" associated. Let's assume I want the amount of days there were no records made by the cleaning lady in a certain month.

How can I do that?

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO
(
    ID_CONTA_CONSUMO  INT
        CONSTRAINT FK_LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO REFERENCES CONTA_CONSUMO (ID),
    LINHA             INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO PRIMARY KEY (ID_CONTA_CONSUMO, LINHA),
    ID_ARTIGO_CONSUMO INT
        CONSTRAINT FK_LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO_ARTIGO REFERENCES ARTIGO_CONSUMO (ID),
    DATA_REGISTO      DATE,
    QUANTIDADE        INT,
    PRECO_UNITARIO    NUMBER(6, 2),
    ID_CAMAREIRA      INT
        CONSTRAINT FK_LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO_CAM REFERENCES CAMAREIRA (ID)
);
```

This is my current function, I need to add the amount of days there were no records made by each cleaning lady to the cursor CURSOR_CAMAREIRA:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FNCOBTERREGISTOMENSALCAMAREIRA(MES_PARAM INT, ANO_PARAM INT) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    IS
    CURSOR_CAMAREIRA SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    -- COLOCA NO CURSOS CAMAREIRA O ID, O NOME, O SOMATORIO DE TODOS OS REGISTOS EFETUADOS, A DATA DO PRIMEIRO
    -- REGISTO E A DATA DO ULTIMO REGISTO. EFETUA UM JOIN NAS TABELAS FUNCIONARIO PARA IR BUSCAR NOME E
    -- LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO PARA IR BUSCAR A RESTANTE INFORMACAO. OS DADOS ESTAO AGRUPADOS PELO NOME/ID DA CAMAREIRA
    OPEN CURSOR_CAMAREIRA FOR
    SELECT C.ID,
           F.NOME,
           SUM(LCC.QUANTIDADE * LCC.PRECO_UNITARIO) AS CONSUMO_TOTAL,
           MIN(LCC.DATA_REGISTO) AS PRIMEIRO_REGISTO,
           MAX(LCC.DATA_REGISTO) AS ULTIMO_REGISTO
      FROM CAMAREIRA C
      JOIN FUNCIONARIO F
        ON F.ID = C.ID
      JOIN LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO LCC
        ON LCC.ID_CAMAREIRA = C.ID
     WHERE (ANO_PARAM IS NULL AND
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LCC.DATA_REGISTO) = MES_PARAM AND
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LCC.DATA_REGISTO) =
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1)
        OR (ANO_PARAM IS NOT NULL AND
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LCC.DATA_REGISTO) = MES_PARAM AND
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LCC.DATA_REGISTO) = ANO_PARAM)
     GROUP BY C.ID, F.NOME;

    RETURN CURSOR_CAMAREIRA;
END;
```

For instance if I have:

| ID_CONTA_CONSUMO | LINHA | ID_ARTIGO_CONSUMO | DATA_REGISTO | QUANTIDADE | PRECO_UNITARIO | ID_CAMAREIRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 295 | 1 | 54 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 5 | 900.00 | 14 |
| 296 | 1 | 55 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 6.00 | 15 |
| 324 | 1 | 23 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 13 |
| 297 | 1 | 56 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 5.00 | 16 |
| 298 | 1 | 57 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | 4.00 | 17 |
| 325 | 1 | 24 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | 7.00 | 14 |
| 299 | 1 | 58 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 3.00 | 18 |
| 354 | 1 | 53 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 13 |
| 326 | 1 | 25 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 6.00 | 15 |
| 300 | 1 | 59 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 2.00 | 19 |

As you can see DATA_REGISTO refers to the date and If I choose the Month 1 of 2020, there were 10 registered comsumptions, I want the cursor to have the information that there were 31-10 (21) days without registered consumption.

I only register the consumptions, not the days without them!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done, sorry for not adding in the first place!

Comment: You need a `left join` with a month_days table. You can use a recursive cte inside your cursor query for this purpose. Otherwise, you cannot filter your table by the dates where the "camareira" didn't go (you won't have any record, huh?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NVL2()` function, which will count the `NULL` values of the date values(`DATA_REGISTO`), within `SUM()` aggregation, and then subtracting the number of days within the current month such as

```
AVG(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(DATA_REGISTO),'dd'))) 
- SUM(NVL2(LCC.DATA_REGISTO,1,0)) AS NO_CLEANING_LADY
```

(*as you don't care count of distinct days*)

while converting the line with joining the table `LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO` to

```
LEFT JOIN LINHA_CONTA_CONSUMO LCC
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast input! I added now the sample data, could you please read what I have in the database and help me again? sorry for the inconvenience, your answer did not solve my problem

Comment: then try new style containing `LAST_DAY()` function from which I'm extracting the total number of days for that current month as you desired @RafaelMoreira

Comment: you're welcome @RafaelMoreira , have a nice day!

Comment: I'm sorry, any way you can explain to me why the AVG function on the subtraction?

Comment: because that part also be aggregated as not placed within the GROUP BY-list @RafaelMoreira , and the value(`31`) is constant for an individual month.

Comment: Ohhh I see I see, thank you again man, you just saved me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of *days* in the month with no records:

```
(extract(day from max(last_day(data_registro)) -
 count(distinct trunc(data_registo))
) as no_data_registo
```

Comment: This is clean, thanks, I used it and it was easy to understand as well!

Comment: @RafaelMoreira . . . I'm surprised then that you didn't accept this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but as I understood the only answer and it was a matter or not changing the joins and other structure I accepted the other.